# Replace special character (é - e-acute) in directory names - using find and rename

Tags: linux, rename

I have a lot of folders with e-acute in their directory names and files, and I'd like to replace these.

So, I need to replace: é with e. Like so:

```
CARRÉ JEWELLERY // initial
CARRE JEWELLERY // after convert
```

I have tried with this, but `find` doesn't work with e-acute.

```
find . -name '*É*' -type d -exec echo rename 's/É/E/g' {} \;
```

It seems as though `rename` doesn't work either with e-acute. I have tried like so:

```
find . -name '*' -type d -exec sh -c "rename 's/É/E/g'" {} \;
```

The command takes quite a while to execute but no names are changed.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive, so don't search for lowercase if the filename has upper case; or use `-iname`, but then the rename command will give unexpected results as-is. The last thing you show with the `<0301>` needs explaining, what were you trying to do there?

Comment: If you are entering the "special characters" literally, you might have run into a problem with your character coding schemes. Are you sure it is set to the same (e.g. UTF-8) _everywhere_ in your system?

Comment: I have tried both (with capital E - question has been edited). `LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"`

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav to test before i execute. i'll remove that when I want to perform the actual command. like a "dry" run.

Comment: You can test with  `rename -n`

Comment: @roaima ok anyhow, this is not related to my problem

Comment: Works for me. `env | grep LC_` returns nothing but `locale` includes `LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"`. Then `touch 'Carré jewellery'` and `ls -l Carr*`. Then `find -maxdepth 1 -name '*é*'` returns me the file, and `rename 's/é/e/g' Carr*` renames it. Trying `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` fails on my system with `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory`, but I can set `LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"` if I choose.